# Using Math to calculate a percentage

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

OK, imagine I have a single column with 200 rows, in each row is a value either 4,8,2 or 0. Is there a way to divide the COUNT of times 2 and 0 occur against the COUNT of times 4 and 8 occur? Like this:

```
(COUNT(2, 0) / COUNT(4, 8)) * 100
```

Thanks! :)

EDIT:

Got a Divide By 0 error on the following statement, although doing COUNT(*) where Completion_Event_Type_Key IN (2,0) OR (8,4) returns over 3000000 rows

```
SELECT DISTINCT 

  SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name AS 'School', ((SELECT COUNT(*) where CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key IN (2,0))/(SELECT COUNT(*) where CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key IN (4, 8)))*100

FROM [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Fact_Admission] AS FA

INNER JOIN [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Student_Demographics] AS SD ON SD.Student_Demographics_Key = FA.Student_Demographics_Key

INNER JOIN [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Fact_SDR_Course_Completion] AS CC ON FA.Student_Demographics_Key = CC.Student_Demographics_Key

GROUP BY 

 SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name, CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key

ORDER BY SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name
```

Comment: Is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
select 
    sum(case when value in (2,0) then 1 else 0 end) / 
    sum(case when value in (4,8) then 1 else 0 end) * 100
from table
```

Beware division by zero, though. You might need special handling if there could be no rows with 4,8.

Given the query in your question, your SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT     
    SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name AS 'School', 
    sum(case when CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key IN (2,0) then 1 else 0 end) / 
    sum(case when CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key IN (4,8) then 1 else 0 end) * 100       

FROM [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Fact_Admission] AS FA

INNER JOIN [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Dim_Student_Demographics] AS SD ON SD.Student_Demographics_Key = FA.Student_Demographics_Key    
INNER JOIN [AUTDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Fact_SDR_Course_Completion] AS CC ON FA.Student_Demographics_Key = CC.Student_Demographics_Key

GROUP BY SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name, CC.Completion_Event_Type_Key

ORDER BY SD.Last_Secondary_School_Name
```

Comment: Using this I got a division by Zero error, although when I separately run a query counting all the times value IN (4,8) I get 1731325

Comment: Really using this, or the query you put in your question?

Comment: Using this statemnt, although the error was my fault, I changed my Join statements around and now it's not giving the error, but will return 0, not quite the answer I expected

Comment: If I slelect top 1 an answer is returned (wrong answer though) but if I let it slelect all rows, the divide by 0 error occurs

Comment: Still get the error with that code (btw you missed the end statements on the case's), I must have a record somewhere that returns 0, time to go searching! haha

Comment: Thanks, fixed. You could try removing the division and multiplication, just grab both numbers in their own column: `select df.last_school_name, sum(case ... end) as twozero, sum(case ... end) as foureight`. Then you can see where the zero is.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'v done, as it turns out there's a shit-load of 0's floating around :( I'll just return the columns separately and do something else with the data. Thanks for the help!